# Catan Seafarers Bonus points when you build a new settlement on a new island in certain scenarios

Tags: catan-seafarers

In Catan Seafarers scenarios where you earn two bonus points for your first settlement on a new island, what happens when you upgrade that settlement to a City? How many points is that now worth?

Answer (score 2):

You get the two bonus points for the first build on the island. 
If you change the settlement to a city, it is not the first build anymore. So you keep the bonus points for the settlement.

Comment: Thank you , Just to clarify it acts as two victory points so when adding up points it would be 1 point for settlement and two victory points for first settlement. If the settlement changes to city , then it would be two points for city plus the 2 victory Points earned  for original settlement , is that correct ?

Comment: If you build the city, it is 2 points for the city and 2 points for the first build bonus. For a total of 4 points.